# Colocar valor Json na variavel

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

O que estou fazendo errado?

```
var GETEstado = $(this).val(json[0].GETEstado);
alert (GETEstado);
```

O alert esta exibindo

> [object Object]

O meu código completo:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".transportadora").click(function () {
        id = $("input[type=radio][name='transportadora']:checked").val();
        estado = $("#estado2").val();
        $.getJSON("cotacoesBuscaTransportadora.php", {
            id_transportadora: id,
            estado: estado
        }, function (json) {
            $("#estadoT").val(json[0].estadoT);
            $("#valorCap").val(json[0].valorCap);
            $("#valorExcedCap").val(json[0].valorExcedCap);
            $("#valorAloremCap").val(json[0].valorAloremCap);
            $("#prazoCap").val(json[0].prazoCap);

            var GETEstado = JSON.stringify(json[0].GETEstado);
            var ResulteZero = JSON.stringify(json[0].ResulteZero);

        });
    });
});

jQuery(function ($) {
    if (GETEstado == "") {
        $.gritter.add({
            title: 'Erro',
            text: 'Preencha os dados do destinatário',
            class_name: 'gritter-error gritter-center'
        });
    }
    if (ResulteZero == 0) {
        $.gritter.add({
            title: 'Erro',
            text: 'Essa transportadora não entrega no estado de destino ou destino não cadastrado.',
            class_name: 'gritter-error gritter-center'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Usando o `JSON.stringify` funcionou, o que não estou conseguindo fazer é levar o valor da variável para outra função onde ira mostrar uma mensagem na tela. http://jsfiddle.net/zLqf3ccr/, veja nesse link.

Comment: Tiago, é isto que queres: http://jsfiddle.net/zLqf3ccr/1/ ?

Comment: @Sergio, sim, mas precisa estar dentro do `jQuery(function($) {` senão não carrega a mensagem.

Comment: Não, mas podes ter de usar `jQuery` em vêz de `$`: http://jsfiddle.net/zLqf3ccr/2/

Comment: @Sergio mais uma vez, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O jQuery retorna coisas diferentes caso seja usado como *getter* ou *setter*.

Se usares `$(this).val(json[0].GETEstado)` estás a usar como um *setter* e vai retornar um objeto jQuery, e não um *numero* ou *string* com valor que foi setado.

Se usares `$(this).val()`aí vai retornar o valor do `this`.

Se o teu alert é para confirmar que o valor foi setado corretamente deves fazer assim:

```
$(this).val(json[0].GETEstado);
var GETEstado = $(this).val();
alert (GETEstado);
```

Para além disso o problema que tens no código é de assincronísmo. O `$.getJSON` vai buscar os dados e depois precisa de correr a segunda parte do teu código a partir da sua função callback. Assim:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".transportadora").click(function () {
        id = $("input[type=radio][name='transportadora']:checked").val();
        estado = $("#estado2").val();
        $.getJSON("cotacoesBuscaTransportadora.php", {
            id_transportadora: id,
            estado: estado
        }, function (json) {
            $("#estadoT").val(json[0].estadoT);
            $("#valorCap").val(json[0].valorCap);
            $("#valorExcedCap").val(json[0].valorExcedCap);
            $("#valorAloremCap").val(json[0].valorAloremCap);
            $("#prazoCap").val(json[0].prazoCap);

            var GETEstado = JSON.stringify(json[0].GETEstado);
            var ResulteZero = JSON.stringify(json[0].ResulteZero);
            //alert (GETEstado);
            next(GETEstado, ResulteZero);
        });
    });
});


function next(GETEstado, ResulteZero) {
    alert(GETEstado);
    if (GETEstado == "") {
        jQuery.gritter.add({
            title: 'Erro',
            text: 'Preencha os dados do destinatário',
            class_name: 'gritter-error gritter-center'
        });
    }
    if (ResulteZero == 0) {
        jQuery.gritter.add({
            title: 'Erro',
            text: 'Essa transportadora não entrega no estado de destino ou destino não cadastrado.',
            class_name: 'gritter-error gritter-center'
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Usando o `JSON.stringify` funcionou, o que não estou conseguindo fazer é levar o valor da variável para outra função onde ira mostrar uma mensagem na tela. http://jsfiddle.net/zLqf3ccr/, veja nesse link.

Comment: @Tiago, é isto que queres: http://jsfiddle.net/zLqf3ccr/1/ ?

Answer (score 2):

O `$(this).val(valor)` preenche o campo e retorna o objeto jQuery correspondente, ou seja, `$(this)`. Por isso o alert mostra essa representação de objeto em texto que você recebeu.

Se o campo estiver sendo preenchido corretamente, basta alterar um pouco seu código:

```
var GETEstado = json[0].GETEstado;
$(this).val(GETEstado);
alert (GETEstado);
```

Comment: Nossa, nem tinha percebido isso, fui para um caminho completamente diferente. Acho que vou excluir minha resposta. Hehe.

Comment: Espera um pouco mais o feedback dele, talvez falta ainda parsear o JSON...

Comment: Usando o `JSON.stringify` funcionou, o que não estou conseguindo fazer é levar o valor da variável para outra função onde ira mostrar uma mensagem na tela. http://jsfiddle.net/zLqf3ccr/, veja nesse link.